# Scotty post type wont allow effects

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, scotty

With:

```
mailHandler = do 
  name  <- param "name"
  email <- param "email"
  renderSendMail $ forwardMail name email

main = scotty 3000 $ post "/mail" mailHandler
```

I get the following type error:

```
    Couldn't match type `IO'
                  with `Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ActionT T.Text IO'
    Expected type: Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ActionT T.Text IO ()
      Actual type: IO ()
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: renderSendMail $ forwardMail name email
    In the expression:
      do { name <- param "name";
           email <- param "email";
           renderSendMail $ forwardMail name email }
    In an equation for `mailHandler':
        mailHandler
          = do { name <- param "name";
                 email <- param "email";
                 renderSendMail $ forwardMail name email }
Failed to install server-0.0.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
server-0.0.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

After spending several hours, I still don't see how to resolve this. If I use a function internal to Scotty, no problem, but if I want to handling anything externally I get the error above. How can I get past this `Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ActionT T.Text IO ()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ActionT T.Text IO ()` is a *monad transformer* over `IO`. These usually implement the `MonadIO` class, so that you can use the `liftIO` function (from `Control.Monad.IO.Class`, if it hasn't been imported already) to "lift" `IO` actions into them:

```
liftIO . renderSendMail $ forwardMail name email
```

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, please tell me the name of the cabal package to install to get `Control.Monad.IO.Class`. And even better if you can explain this whole monad transformer concept

Comment: ok, I got `transformers` installed and things are alive again, but would still love an explanation of the concept.

Comment: @Fresheyeball `scotty` seems to already depend on `transformers`, so I suspect that was redundant? (Since `scotty` defines a transformer itself, it sort of has to.)

Comment: @Fresheyeball Monad transformers is a somewhat big subject, so I think I'll pass on explaining it all here, but see e.g. [this Wikibook chapter](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers).

Comment: @Fresheyeball Also this paper: http://www.grabmueller.de/martin/www/pub/Transformers.pdf